# Am I able to access Chrome web history from a desktop app?

Tags: security, google-chrome, permissions, google-chrome-extension, desktop-application

Is it possible for a standalone desktop app to access browsing history within Chrome/Firefox/IE?

Or is that impossible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Chrome/Firefox store their history in a SQLite database, IE stores the history information in a special folder. For advanced information on these locations, see http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/windows-forensics-registry-and-file-system-spots

Answer (score 2):

I’ve poked around at Chrome history a couple times when trying to search for something that I couldn’t find from the History Tab. Here’s a tutorial: [Google Chrome Forensics](http://computer-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/01/21/google-chrome-forensics/). Some notes:

- The sqlite3 databases are “locked” when Chrome is running, so you might have to either close Chrome or copy the databases to a separate file before reading them.
- In the History database, the `visit_time` is μs since 1601-01-01 (1/10th the Windows filetime) even if you’re on Mac or Linux, so to convert it to Unix time (s since 1970-01-01) you have to scale and subtract `11644473600 = new Date(1970, 0, 1)/1000 - new Date(1601, 0, 1)/1000`.
- E.g., Find the last 10 URLs I visited: `select urls.url, datetime(visit_time/1000000 - 11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') from visits left join urls on visits.url = urls.id order by visit_time desc limit 10;`
- The `visits.transition&255` is an enum found in [page_transition_types.h](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/content/public/common/page_transition_types.h?view=markup). See the descriptions within the [extension documentation on history](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html).

Comment: 100 ns intervals; not μs intervals (order of magnitude off)

Comment: @BillyONeal, you’re right that Windows file time counts by 100ns, but that query works so the Chrome visit_time is 1/10 the Windows time. Will update.

Comment: @BillyONeal, I was just wondering why they chose Windows epoch, and according to [this cookie expiration bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=14734), it’s so that there’s always a distinction between zero-initialized times and any real time, since this was true in Windows where Chrome was first released. And Chrome’s tick has always been µs.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed.

Chrome and Firefox store browser history in sql-lite files.

The location of the chrome history file is :

```
Linux: /home/$USER/.config/google-chrome/
Linux: /home/$USER/.config/chromium/
Windows Vista (and Win 7): C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\[USERNAME]\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\
```

If your developing the app in question. I've used Java in the past. You'll have to read up on the structure of the SQLlite database but you can access the tables using SQL queries (its quite nice to do with groovy actually). It works for Firefox the exact same way.

I have no experience with IE history.